# Azure Synapse insert result of exec into a table

Tags: exec, azure-synapse

Is there a way to insert into temp table result dataset from **exec** (no matter call of the procedure or execute dynamic SQL) in Azure Synapse Analytics? I didn't find valid examples in the documentation.

E.g.:

```
create procedure dbo.test
       as select 1
create table #t1 (id int) 
insert into #t1
exec test
```

*Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'exec'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the workaround like below:

```
 exec ('select ' + @myDynamicCode + ' into #t1')
```